# Accessing process stack pointer from kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was able to get task_struct from current macro and am wondering if there is a way to get the process stack pointer from my custom sys_call to return to userspace(as readonly value)??

Comment: You have to tell what your custom sys_call does?

Comment: you can refer ptregs structure which holds userspace context saved during syscall entrance

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get it's value in assembly, so try using this:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t getsp(void)
{
    uint64_t sp;
    asm("mov %%rsp, %0" : "=rm" (sp));
    return sp;
}
```